# Monaco editor for vue generates lots of .js files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, monaco-editor

I am implementing vue-monaco plugin inside Laravel application using Vue.

The steps are rather easy, I install the [vue-monaco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-monaco) like:

```
npm install vue-monaco
```

Then in my Vue file I import the monaco editor like:

```
import MonacoEditor from 'vue-monaco'
```

I don't even use it, just import it and then run `npm run watch`. This result in npm creating exactly 63 files in my public folder, like in the image below (first 15 are shown, 63 are being created).

Why does this happen and how can I bypass it?

[image]

Comment: Just speculating but might they be webpack bundle chunks that misplaced?

Comment: How can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

`vue-monaco` is basically a VScode in your webview, right ? If it's the case, it's probably creating some configuration files for it to work and this is totally normal.

What's the content of those files and the content of your `package.json` (`npm run watch`) ?

If you want to custom some options for this plugin, it looks like that you will need to dive into those settings: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#create and pass it as props to `vue-monaco` (this info is taken from the doc itself).

Otherwise, creating a simple vue project can help debug things too IMO, see if the files are created in public too or if it's more of a `laravel` configuration issue. Then, you could maybe try the github issue of the main JS project: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues?q=is%3Aissue

Comment: Tried going with the configuration options, nothing seems to help. The files being generated are actually formatters for the different languages the editor supports (like html, css, js, rust, go etc.). I don't need them, but I can not find a way to eliminate them from pollution my public folder.

Comment: They are maybe required to use the plugin. That way, you don't need to link them to the editor since they are available in the public directory.